# MySQL timeseries weighed average using window functions

Tags: mysql, mariadb, query-performance, window-functions

I have a simple `data` table for timeseries data, basically only timestamp and value:

```
Field, Type, Null, Key, Default, Extra
'id','int(11)','NO','PRI',NULL,'auto_increment'
'channel_id','int(11)','YES','MUL',NULL,''
'timestamp','bigint(20)','NO','',NULL,''
'value','double','NO','',NULL,''
```

I have developed a somewhat sophisticated query for calculating weighed average by period, basically calculating `sum(val x delta time)`. The `@prev_timestamp` variable basically simulates the `LAG()` function. Example:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(agg.timestamp) AS timestamp, 
    COALESCE( 
        SUM(agg.val_by_time) / (MAX(agg.timestamp) - MIN(agg.prev_timestamp)), 
        AVG(agg.value)
    ) AS value
FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        timestamp, 
        value, 
        value * (timestamp - @prev_timestamp) AS val_by_time, 
        COALESCE(@prev_timestamp, 0) AS prev_timestamp, 
        @prev_timestamp := timestamp 
    FROM data 
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT @prev_timestamp := NULL
    ) AS vars 
    WHERE channel_id=56  AND timestamp >= 1546297161097 AND timestamp <= 1552950000000 
    ORDER BY timestamp ASC
) AS agg 
GROUP BY (timestamp - 1546288811393) >> 23 
ORDER BY timestamp ASC
;
```

Recently, I've converted this query from the hacky MySQL variable approach to use window functions:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(agg.timestamp) AS timestamp, 
    COALESCE(
        SUM(agg.val_by_time) / (MAX(agg.timestamp) - MIN(agg.prev_timestamp)), 
        AVG(agg.value)
    ) AS value
FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        timestamp, 
        value, 
        LAG(timestamp) OVER(ORDER BY channel_id, timestamp ASC) AS prev_timestamp,
        value * (timestamp - LAG(timestamp) OVER(ORDER BY channel_id,timestamp ASC)) AS val_by_time
    FROM data 
    WHERE channel_id=56  
    AND timestamp >= 1546297161097 AND timestamp <= 1552950000000 
    ORDER BY timestamp ASC

) AS agg 
GROUP BY (timestamp - 1546288811393) >> 23 
ORDER BY timestamp ASC
;
```

The downside is that the version using window functions- though apparently cleaner- runs about 25% slower (MariaDB 10.3, Raspi 3).

Is there a better (more performant) way to write this query by making better use of the window function, maybe getting rid of the derived table?

Comment: If you are processing the rows one at a time, in order, it _may_ be better to fetch the rows in order into your application, then do the arithmetic there.  SQL is good at mass operations, but not good at sequential operations.